# regular expression string search in python with similar string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to very the presence of a series of given substring within a larger string in python 3.7 using Regular Expression. The problem is similar to this:

```
import re
LargeString = 'Lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry RE-2 and other Lorem ipsum RE-44'
substringSet = ['RE-2','RE-44','RE-4']
for _c in substringSet:
    _idxDevice = re.findall(_c,LargeString)
```

Clear in this way the regular expression will give a positive answer for all the elements of the substringSet whereas I would like to be able to distinguish the fact that RE-44 is present in the LargeString wherease RE-4 not. Any idea?

Comment: Add a word boundary `\b` at the end of each pattern. (read a basic tutorial about regex patterns).

Comment: if you need just to check the presentence of every item of your substringSet, then check my variant from answers. If not then please add more details

Comment: @dukkee your solution works great. Actually I was unable to use the word boundary solution proposed, but I guess this depends from my implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your current code is bad? Just add

```
>>> import re
>>> large_string = 'Lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry RE-2 and other Lorem ipsum RE-44'
>>> substring_set = ['RE-2', 'RE-44', 'RE-4']
>>> {pattern: bool(re.search(f"({pattern} )|({pattern}$)", large_string)) for pattern in substring_set}
{'RE-2': True, 'RE-44': True, 'RE-4': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple idea, add everything you find in an array then perform operations either within the loop or on the array later. Using set will add values only once.

```
import re
LargeString = 'Lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry RE-2 and other Lorem ipsum RE-44'
substringSet = ['RE-2','RE-44','RE-4']
present=set()
for _c in substringSet:
    _idxDevice = re.findall(_c,LargeString)
    present.add(_c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the substrings into one regular expression that looks form them all but prioritizes the longer substrings.

```
import re
LargeString = 'Lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry RE-2 and other Lorem ipsum RE-44'
substringSet = ['RE-2','RE-44','RE-4']           # RE-44 must be placed before RE-4
allSubs = "|".join(map(re.escape,substringSet))  # r'RE\-2|RE\-44|RE\-4'

found = [*re.findall(allSubs,LargeString)]  # ['RE-2', 'RE-44']
for _c in substringSet:
    _idxDevice = [_c]*found.count(_c) # repeated _c as you original code would
    print(_idxDevice)

['RE-2']
['RE-44']
[]
```